# Forefront TMG 2010: Can you monitor realtime TCP connections and bandwidth on a per-user basis?

Tags: proxy, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-ftmg, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I'm just starting a trial of ForeFront TMG to use as a proxy server.

I know I can get a real time activity monitor and filter on a per user basis, but would like to be able to get a real time activity monitor of all users that I can then sort by bandwidth consumed (enabling me to get a view on who the bandwidth hogs are).

Does anyone know if this is possible in Forefront TMG or if a third party product is required?

Thanks.

JR

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use an add on like [bandwidth splitter](http://www.bsplitter.com/)

Comment: Indeed, we've used bandwidth splitter for a few years now. It has some nifty features, like quotas.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, TMG 2010 doesn't have realtime bandwidth monitoring. Live Logging is about as close as you get to that - another product would be required for what you're after.

Answer (score -3):

You may use gfi Webmonitor for TMG plugin, Surfcop, Netfee & Websense etc...